How to add a "scroll to top"-button?
I need to a add a scroll to top button in my Blazor server-side app. I have found this How T o - Scroll Back To Top Button article and can follow it till it comes to add the javascript code.
As I'm a newbie in js, how do I add the code in a Blazor app? (I already have a site.js file in wwwroot.

The documentation covers this.  Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-9.0 and if you still can't get it to work, explain exactly what code you tgried that didn't work.  If you want someone to just give you code from scratch, start with ChatGPT rather than StackOverflow.

There is mostly no need for extra JavaScript for this requirement.
See this sample component ScrollTo.razor which handles it without external JS.
Usage with an ElementReference
<h1 @ref=@ScrollToReference>My heading</h1>
...
...
<ScrollTo ScrollTargetElement=@ScrollToReference>Top</ScrollTo>

@code {
private ElementReference? ScrollToReference;
}

renders an anchor tag but uses ScrollToReference.FocusAsync() to scroll to the target element.
<a href="/mypage#top">Top</a>  

Usage with an Element Id
<h1 id="myheading">My heading</h1>
...
...
<ScrollTo ScrollTargetId="myheading">Top</ScrollTo>

renders an anchor tag that just works
<a href="/mypage#top">Top</a>  

ScrollTo.razor
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<a href=@ScrollTarget 
   @onclick=Clicked 
   @onclick:preventDefault=@shouldPreventDefault>
 @ChildContent
</a>

@code {
    /// <summary>
    /// The markup to display inside the anchor tag.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = @<span>Top</span>;

    /// <summary>
    /// An element to scroll to.
    /// Use this OR <see cref="ScrollTargetId"/>, not both.
    /// If you use this property, you might want to set <see cref="AnchorName"/> to a reasonable value so the browser address bar shows a meaningful fragment.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public ElementReference? ScrollTargetElement { get; set; } = default;

    /// <summary>
    /// An element id to scroll to.
    /// Use this OR <see cref="ScrollTargetElement"/>, not both.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string? ScrollTargetId { get; set; } = default;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Anchor name to use with an ElementReference - this becomes the current Uri fragment. e.g. /home#name
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string? AnchorName { get; set; } = "top";

    private string ScrollTarget
        => (ScrollTargetElement, ScrollTargetId) switch
        {
            // For ElementReference ScrollTo use the supplied AnchorName
            (ElementReference _, _) => $"{pageUri}#{AnchorName}",

            // For ElementId ScrollTo use the supplied ElementId
            (_, string elementId) => $"{pageUri}#{elementId.TrimStart('#')}",

            // For neither ElementReference nor ElementId ScrollTo use the default "top"
            _ => $"{pageUri}#top"
        };

    private string pageUri => pageRoute ?? navigationManager.Uri;

    private string? pageRoute;

    private bool shouldPreventDefault => ScrollTargetElement is ElementReference;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // get the current page Uri
        if (Uri.TryCreate(navigationManager.Uri, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri? result))
        {
            pageRoute = result.AbsolutePath;
        }
    }

    async Task Clicked()
    {

        if (ScrollTargetElement is ElementReference target)
        {
            // set the browser address bar
            navigationManager.NavigateTo($"{pageUri}#{AnchorName?.TrimStart('#')}");
            // scroll to the intended element
            await target.FocusAsync();
        }
    }
}

